# Setting Private Class Variable in Shared Method

Tags: vb.net

Why is it possible to set the value of a private variable from within a Shared method?  Is this valid OOP, or a quirk of VB.NET?

```
Public Class Wednesday

    Private _name As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Sub Update(ByVal item As Wednesday)

        item._name = "Tom"

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `private` means *only accessible within the class*, and not *only accessible within the instance*.

Have a look at the documenatation of the [Access Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx):

> **Private**
>
> The Private (Visual Basic) keyword in the declaration statement specifies that the elements can be accessed only from within the same module, class, or structure.

And since your `Update` method is a member if the `Wednesday` class, it can access `private` members of a `Wednesday` instance.